# A simple second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I try and solve the equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=-k^2\psi
\end{equation}

I get a solution in the form of:

\begin{equation}
\psi=Ae^{-ikx} +Be^{ikx}
\end{equation}

which I believe is right, but I often see the answer written as:
\begin{equation}
\psi=Asin(kx)+Bcos(kx)
\end{equation}

which I believe is just obtained using Euler's formula but I feel like if that's the case, then the sin terms would cancel out. Can someone explain how to go from the first form to the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\psi=Ae^{-ikx} +Be^{ikx}=A\Big(\cos(kx)-i\sin(kx)\Big)+B\Big(\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)\Big)$$ Now expand and group together the $\sin(kx)$ and the $\cos(kx)$.

So $$\psi=(A+B)\cos(kx)+i(B-A)\sin(kx)=C \cos(kx)+D\sin(kx)$$ In the two expressions you wrote, $A$ is no more $A$ and $B$ is no more $B$ .